# Almost-correct answers

Tags: discussion, answers

Sometimes answers are posted, which *almost* comply with the specs. They might be a clever, interesting take on the problem, but not follow one of the rules, or the program might crash in a few rare cases. What should be done with these answers? Upvote, downvote, or delete?

Answer (score 10):

Depending on the question/answer, I'd say leave a comment pointing out the flaw and wait for the user to fix their answer. It wouldn't be fair for others to allow the answer to stay, but on the other hand deleting is too harsh for an answer that almost works.

If fixing the answer breaks their clever code, then they can leave it in their post as a bonus footnote if they wish.

Comment: I think this applies most to *accidental* flaws. If an answerer clearly knows (mentions it, etc) that it doesn't conform to spec and *doesn't include code that does*, I downvote whether it's clever or not. Deletion (for me) depends on the answer quality in general.

Comment: As long as answer doesn't contain malicous code, comment is good. Otherwise it should be immediately deleted or flagged if your reputation isn't enough for deleting. It's very good that we doesn't have much of those.